# Wait until driver instance has probed

Tags: linux

I have written a Linux driver that is contained in a module. The `probe()` function sets up the hardware and creates a device file for userspace usage with `device_create()`. The `device_create()` is the last thing in the probe function.

I load the kernel module through the `init_module` syscall. It seems to me that the probe function is run as a callee of the syscall, i.e. that the probe function is done once the syscall returns to userspace. However I am not sure about this.

Sometimes, right after module insertion, the device file that is created through `device_create` is not there yet.

What is the correct way to wait for the driver has probed and all the effects of the probe such as created device files are visible?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is waiting for node creation events in /dev by "inotify" API, provided that you can foresee the name. Here the official description and an example: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html